# Spoken unsubtitled Min in a (now deleted) Youtube video: characters?

Tags: topolect, spelling, hokkien

Long ago, I ran into [the song 媽媽歌星](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAW9YPnJo2E), and in particular I have a download of a video where there were two spoken parts in Min, without captions. It is rather unfortunate that the video in question is now no longer retriavable on Youtube, or at least I cannot find it. Anyways, yesterday I tried transcribing it (as I heard it) with Tai-lo, getting the following:

> Lin ho. Mama tui lang kong | li si gua e siau ting. | Li i-king | kam-kak tsin khi-kuai mo? | So si kong | tshiu mama tsip kuan | lun liong e lu-sing. | Tsit-si-lang | kan-na oo a kho tshiu gua. | Tu hui si i gua, | ia ko - sing li khau long - ho tsui le. Li ia so tsai-iann | mama tsi ai - sit lin pa-pa tsit e lang, | ki-lian bo lin pa-pa, | gua | tsi ho kho tsu-pi, | kho tshiu gua, | tshiu gua - tng lai ko - kua le. | Ui-tioh bo guan hoo gua beh si-bong. | In ho. | Mama an-ne - mua pian lang, | li siunn. | Tioh m tioh? | Tioh m tioh le? (Part 1)

And:

> Lin ho. | Mama iong hui, | iong en tsi, | am khan lioh bin - sion me liau kun, | tann ban tioh iau kiann wei mou i. | M gun pat-lang - an tsong sim. | Mama tsi hi-bang lin | siong sim guo. | Liau-kai gua: | li si mama e sinn-mia. | Li kam tsai-iann mama | fui ia mng lin pan | ti e din mang - tiong. | Li si tsit e - tsin phiau-phiat e sim-nong. | Li e sin-khu-pi | kiau ua tsit e - tsin sui, | tsin sui e sinn-mia. | Ah, | m tsai siann-mih si-tsun, | tsi kho-i nai tsit tsi | na jin tsiann nai kau. | M si | e ting nai ka | nai kau | mama m tsai beh luann - huann-hi le. | Li tsai-iann bo? (Part 2)

The `|`s and `-`s indicate pauses and slow-downs in speech speed respectively. Then I tried giving this sound transcription characters, and got this:

> 林好。妈妈对人讲你是我的小^灯^。你已经感觉真奇^怪^无？鎖^匙^讲^就^妈妈 tsip kuan | lun liong 的女生。一世人干那 oo a kho tshiu gua. | Tu hui si i gua, | ia ko - sing li khau long 予碎^咧。你也所^知影，妈妈只爱识^林爸爸一个人。既然无林爸爸，我只好靠 tsu-pi, 靠 tshiu gua, | tshiu gua 转来 ko - kua 咧。为着无^愿^予我欲失望。林好。妈妈按呢 mua pian 人。你想。着毋着？着毋着咧？ (Part 1)

And:

> 林好。妈妈 iong hui, | iong en tsi, | am khan lioh bin - sion me liau kun, 担 ban 着 iau 惊 wei mou i. 毋 gun 别人 an tsong sim. 妈妈只希望林 siong sim guo. 了解我：你是妈妈的生命。你敢知影妈妈 fui ia mng lin pan | ti e din mang - tiong. 你是一个真 phiau-phiat e sim-nong. 你的 sin-khu-pi 叫我一个真 sui, 真 sui 的生命。啊，毋知啥物时阵，只可^以^ nai tsit tsi | na jin tsiann nai kau. 毋是 e ting nai ka | nai kai 妈妈毋知欲 luann - 欢喜咧。你知影无？ (Part 2)

Technically the transcription above involves a few tweaks done while giving it characters. Characters followed by `^` are of uncertain choice. I suspect `lun-liong` is some kind of adjective. I also suspect `tsip kuan` might be `集權`, `sin-khu-pi` might be `辛苦悲`, `mang - tiong` might be a misheard `梦中`, `真 sui, 真 sui` might be `真媠，真媠`, and `khau long` might have to end with `龙` Anyways, could you help me complete this character spelling and finish understanding this?

**Update**

It seems the video I have on my computer [is still online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-qeiBsc7yE) or has been put back.

Answer (score 5):

[The full lyrics](http://blog.xuite.net/iamlindaliang/twblog/128855991) can be found on the Web.
(But, there are a few minor errors.)

[A video with all subtitles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MPt0r4NgRY) can be found on the YouTube site.
(There are a few minor errors too.)

The lyrics are the words that a mother, who is a singer, tells her daughter whose name is 麗蘭, Lì-lán in Mandarin or Le-lán in Taiwanese Hokkien.

The following lyrics have been modified to Mandarin so that more people can understand the meanings easily.

---

### 媽媽歌星

含 口白 (narration; spoken parts)

note: (can be added) [can be omitted]

人若問 妳和我二人到底甚(麼)關係 (我都)介紹妳是我小妹 (而)不敢講坦白(話)
雖然(我)是一直(在)掩蓋 (其實)心內感覺真(得很)難過 因為我待在歌壇 最需要(的)是歌迷
人若知(道)我有女兒 歲數又這(麼)多 恐怕可比秋天的落花 名聲飄飄墜落地

> 【口白】
> 麗蘭，媽媽對人說，妳是我的小妹，妳一定感覺奇怪吧？
> 事實講，像媽媽這種軟弱的女性，一世人只能依靠著唱歌的女人，除了這以外，又還有什麼工作好做呢？
> 妳也[所]知道，媽媽只愛的是妳爸爸一個人。
> 既然沒你爸爸，我只好靠自己，靠唱歌。
> 唱歌總是要靠歌迷，為著不願給歌迷失望，
> 麗蘭，媽媽這樣瞞騙人，妳想對不對？對不對呢？

一切是環境來造成(這)無聊的命運 滿面的胭脂水粉 打扮(成正)當青春(的樣子)
上舞台表演歌唱 引人迷魂笑紋紋 因為我待在歌壇 靠藝術賺錢[銀]
母子[來]相依為命 勞苦無(可)議論 哪能怨嘆無情的郎君 (令人)每日心[肝]亂紛紛

> 【口白】
> 麗蘭，媽媽用粉用胭脂掩蓋[著]面上的皺紋，打扮著妖嬌的模樣，
> 不管別人怎麼想，媽媽只希望妳相信我，了解我。
> 妳是媽媽的性命，妳可知道，媽媽每晚都做夢；
> 在[眠]夢中，妳是ㄧ個很美很美的新娘，妳的身邊也有一個很瀟灑的新郎。
> 啊！不知何時，這種的場面會到？
> 若真正來到，……
> 不是，ㄧ定會到。
> 若到，媽媽不知有多歡喜咧，妳知道嗎？

(因)興趣[著]唱歌(以)來 一唱已經十多年 親手來[襁]養女兒 不願靠別人
薄情郎離開[了]後 將[著]愛情都全放(下) 因為我待在歌壇 有能力再活動
期待著美麗前程 相信有好夢 用心栽培女兒花清香 是我一生的願望

Comment: Did I guess the Min characters correctly? How do I complete them? The meaning could be useful when translating, but I want the Min so I can reconstruct the Min sounds and (potentially) be able to pronounce them.

Comment: That video has different spoken parts.

Answer (score 0):

Taking from the other answer, I almost completed the characters. They should be:

> 蘭好。媽媽對人說，妳是我的小燈<sup>1</sup>，妳一定感覺真奇怪無？事實講，像媽媽這款軟弱的女性，一世人干焦好啊靠唱歌。除非是以外，也閣啥物頭路好做呢？妳也所知影，媽媽只愛的是蘭爸爸一個人。既然無蘭爸爸，我只好靠自己，靠唱歌。唱歌轉來靠歌迷，為著無願予歌迷失望。蘭好，媽媽按呢瞞騙人。妳想著毋著？著毋著呢？

<sup>1</sup> I heard "siau-ting" and 小妹 would end with "mue", not "ting".

I guess those "lin"s were "lian | 蘭".

And:

> 蘭好。媽媽用粉圓、用胭脂、暗崁著面上的皺痕，打扮著妖嬌的模樣，毋管別人按怎想，媽媽只希望蘭相信我，了解我。妳是媽媽的性命。妳敢知影，媽媽每晚眠夢，佇眠夢中，妳是一個真飄撇的新娘，妳的身軀邊也有一個真媠，真媠的新人。啊！毋知啥物時陣，这款的日子若真正爱到。毋是，一定愛到。若會到，媽媽毋知欲偌歡喜咧。你知影無？

Will add transliteration and translation after I'm done with this blasted exam.

---

**Full simplified versions**

Part 1:

> 恁好。妈妈对人讲妳是我的小灯，妳一定感觉真奇怪无？事实讲，像妈妈这款软弱的女性，一世人干焦好啊靠唱歌。除非这以外，犹阁有啥物头路好做咧？妳也所知影妈妈只爱的是恁爸爸。既然无恁爸爸，我只好靠自己，靠唱歌。唱歌转来靠歌迷，为着无愿予歌迷失望。恁好，妈妈按呢瞒骗人。妳想着毋着？着毋着咧？

Part 2:

> 恁好。妈妈用粉圆、用胭脂、暗崁着面上的皱痕，打扮着妖娇的模样，毋管別人按怎想，妈妈只希望兰相信我，了解我。妳是妈妈的性命。妳敢知影，妈妈每夜晚眠梦，伫咧眠梦中，妳是一个真飘撇的新娘，妳的身躯边也有一个真媠，真媠的新人。啊！毋知啥物时阵，这款的日子若真正爱到。毋是，一定爱到。若到，妈妈毋知欲偌欢喜咧。妳知影无？

**Full translations**

Part 1:

> Hello. If mom tells others you are my little lamp, you'll surely feel pretty strange, right? To tell the truth, a woman as weak as mom can only depend on singing for her whole life. Besides this, what job could she do? You also know mom only loves your dad. Since your dad's no longer here, I can only rely on myself, on singing. Singing I come to rely on fans, because I don't want to let fans down. Hello, mama thus deceives people. Do you think it's right? Is it right or not?

Part 2:

> Hello. Mom uses tapioca balls and lipstick, covering the folds on her face, making up a tender and young look, no matter what others think, mom only hopes you believe in me, understand me. You are mom's life. Do you know that, every night, mom dreams, and in [her] dreams, you are a very aloof and charming new bride, and by your side there is also a very handsome, very handsome new groom? Ah! I don't know what time, [nor] if such a day can really come. No, it will surely come. If it comes, mom doesn't know how happy [she] will be. Do you know?

**Full transliterations**

Part 1:

> Lín hó. Má-mah tuì lâng kóng, lí sī guá ê siáu ting, lí it-tīng | kám-kak tsin kî-kuài--bô? Sū-si̍t kóng, tshiūnn má-mah tsit-khuán | luán-lio̍k ê lú-sìng | tsi̍t-sì-lâng | kan-na hó--ah khò tshiùnn-kua. Tû-hui tsit í-guā, iah-koh ū siánn-mih thâu-lōo hó tsò--leh. Lí iā sóo tsai-iánn, má-mah tsí ài ê sī lín pa-pa tsi̍t ê lâng. Kì-liân bô lin pá-pah, guá | tsí-hó khò tsū-kí, khò tshiùnn-kua. Tshiùnn-kua - tńg-lâi khò kua-bê, uī-tio̍h bô-guān hōo kua-bê sit-bōng. Lín hó. Má-mah án-ne muâ-phiàn lâng. Lí siūnn tio̍h m̄ tio̍h? | Tio̍h m̄ tio̍h--leh?

Part 2:

> Lín hó. Má-mah iōng hún-înn, iōng ian-tsi | àm-khàm-tio̍h bīn siōng ê liâu-hûn, tánn-pān-tio̍h iau-kiau ê bôo-iūnn<sup>1</sup>. M̄-kuán<sup>2</sup> pa̍t-lâng án-tsuánn siūnn, má-mah tsí hi-bāng lín | siong-sìn guá, liáu-kái guá. Lí sī má-mah ê sìnn-miā. Lí kám tsai-iánn má-mah | muí iā-mńg bîn-bāng, tī-leh bîn-bāng tiōng, lí sī tsi̍t ê - tsin phiau-phiat ê sin-niû<sup>3</sup>, lí ê sin-khu-pinn | iā ū tsi̍t ê - tsin suí, | tsin suí ê sin-lâng<sup>4</sup>. Ah, m̄ tsai siánn-mih sî-tsūn, tsit-khuán ê ji̍t-tsí | nā tsin-tsiànn ài kàu. M̄ sī: it-tīng ài kàu. Nā kàu, má-mah m̄ tsai beh guā<sup>5</sup> huann-hí--leh. Lí tsai-iánn--bô?

<sup>1</sup> More like "môo-īnn" or even "môo-uīnn".
<sup>2</sup> More like "M̄-kún".
<sup>3</sup> More like "sin-niông" or even "sin-nòng".
<sup>4</sup> More like "sin-lìn".
<sup>5</sup> That is distinctly a non-sandhied "guâ", that is, it has a clearly rising tone, which is what caused my "-" in the original transliteration attempt.

Comment: 飄撇 | phiau-phiat | 瀟灑 | aloof and charming.

Comment: I think I was right with the "lin"s actually. Only they're spelled 恁好。